# MSBuild or VSbuild task is not working after I updated it to Visual Studio Build tools 2022 from 2019

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I updated my VS build tools 2019 to 2022. Upgraded it for dotnet6. After I updated it to latest one, the pipelines build for dot net framework and dot net 5 failing and throwing error like below

##[error]No agent found in pool DotNet satisfies both of the following demands: Agent.Name, visualstudio. All demands: Agent.Name -equals , msbuild, visualstudio, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.115.0

But the same pipelines working fine on VS Build tools 2019. We are using the Nuget and VS build in the tasks which are failing. For some pipelines which we are using .netcoreCLI, this build tools 22 are working for .netcoreCLI task. There are many pipelines where I can't migrate to .netcoreCLI. Please someone help me to sort out this issue. [[image: Please check the below images][1]]

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> MSBuild or VSbuild task is not working after I updated it to Visual Studio Build tools 2022 from 2019

According to the error message, this shows that your pipeline has added demands, but there are no agents that meet the requirements in your agent pool:

> ##[error]No agent found in pool DotNet satisfies both of the following demands: Agent.Name, visualstudio.

So, please check if your pipeline have set any demands：

[image]

If you set it,please try to remove or you need to check the value for the capabilities of your agent:

[image]